# Call C++ DLL function in Delphi 7

Tags: .net, delphi, dll

I have a DLL written in C++. I want to call a function in it from Delphi 7.

I only have an example written in VB.NET.

I have tried converting the code myself before posting here.

The problem is when I call the function, it gives me wrong output in binary, which obviously means I am doing something wrong with the input.

Here is the original code in VB.NET:

```vb
Private Shared Declare Unicode Function Read_Write Lib "Subway.dll" (obej As IntPtr, Data_in As Byte(), in_siz As Integer, <Out()> ByRef Data_out As IntPtr, ByRef out_siz As Integer) As Integer

Dim obej As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
Dim Data_out As IntPtr = 0
Dim out_siz As Integer = 0
Dim Res As Integer = -1

Res = Read_Write(obej, Encoding.[Default].GetBytes(Mystr), Mystr.Length, Data_out, out_siz)
```

And my converted code in Delphi:

```pascal
function Read_Write(obej: Pointer; Data_in: TByteDynArray; in_siz:Cardinal; var Data_out: TByteDynArray; var out_siz: Cardinal): Integer; stdcall; external 'Subway.dll';

var
  tx, rx: TByteDynArray;
  obej: pointer;
  s:string;
  Res: Integer;
  out_siz: Integer;

SetLength(tx, Length(s));
Move(s[1], tx[0], Length(s));
Res := Read_Write(obej, tx, length(s), rx, out_siz);
```

Orignal call (C language):

```
int __stdcall Read_Write(void *u_arg, const unsigned char  *p_data_in, unsigned int  data_in_len, unsigned char  **pp_data_out, unsigned int  *p_data_out_len);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Delphi declaration of `Read_Write()` does not match the VB.NET declaration. You are not taking into account how .NET marshals parameters to unmanaged languages. Also, `TByteDynArray` is a Delphi-specific type that you can't pass as-is to other languages, particularly in output parameters.

Try something more like this instead:

```pascal
function Read_Write(obej: Pointer; Data_in: PByte; in_siz: Integer, var Data_out: Pointer; var out_siz: Integer): Integer; stdcall; external 'Subway.dll';

var
  obej: Pointer;
  Data_out: Pointer;
  out_siz: Integer;
  Res: Integer;
  MyStr: AnsiString;
  buf: TByteDynArray;
begin
  ...

  obej := nil;
  Data_out := nil;
  out_siz := 0;

  MyStr := ...;
  SetLength(buf, Length(MyStr));
  Move(PAnsiChar(MyStr)^, PByte(buf)^, Length(MyStr));

  Res := Read_Write(obej, PByte(buf), Length(buf), Data_out, out_siz);
  // use Data_out up to out_siz bytes as needed...
  // free Data_out as needed...

  ...
end;
```

Alternatively, you can omit the `TByteDynArray` and just past the `AnsiString` data directly:

```pascal
Res := Read_Write(obej, PByte(PAnsiChar(MyStr)), Length(MyStr), Data_out, out_siz);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried both ways unfortunately i am still getting wrong output, maybe i am ignoring "Encoding.[Default].GetBytes(Mystr)" ??

Comment: @Maaz no, because 1) `Encoding` doesn't exist in Delphi 7, and 2) `AnsiString` is already in the same memory format that `Encoding.Default.GetBytes()` returns. Something else is going on. Do you not have a C/C++ `.h` file for the DLL? That would be really helpful to determine the exact declaration needed for the function. What exactly are you expecting for output, and what are you really getting instead? Please edit your question to show that.

Comment: ok, after some help i found native dll function ....int __stdcall Read_Write(void *u_arg, const unsigned char  *p_data_in, unsigned int  data_in_len, unsigned char  **pp_data_out, unsigned int  *p_data_out_len);.... And about output i compare it and it's not same as orignal so most likely my call method is wrong, Thanks for your patience;

Comment: @Maaz the Delphi translation of that C declaration is `function Read_Write(u_arg: Pointer; const p_data_in: PByte; data_in_len: Cardinal; var pp_data_out: PByte; var p_data_out_len: Cardinal): Integer; stdcall;` which is almost identical to the original declaration I gave you. The output data will be the same regardless of which declaration you use. You haven't answered my question yet about what the output data actually looks like, and what you are expecting it to look like.